# Saturated vapor and liquid densities (VLC curve) from Helmholtz free energy equation of state

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, vapor-pressure, density, statistical-mechanics

I have been reading about the statistical associating fluid theory (SAFT) which computes the Helmholtz free energy ($A$) from the SAFT EoS (*a hell lot of equations*) for a molecule of interest, and is then used in the estimation of intermolecular potential parameters by minimising a relative least-squares objective function ($F$):

$$\min_{\varepsilon,\sigma} F=\sum_{i=1}^{N_{P_{sat}}} \Bigg[\frac{P_{sat,i}^{exp}(T_i)-P_{sat,i}^{calc}(T_i;\sigma,\varepsilon)}{P_{sat,i}^{exp}(T_i)} \Bigg]^2 + \sum_{j=1}^{N_{\rho_{satL}}} \Bigg[\frac{\rho_{satL,j}^{exp}(T_j)-\rho_{satL,j}^{calc}(T_j;\sigma,\varepsilon)}{\rho_{satL,j}^{exp}(T_j)} \Bigg]^2  $$

$P_{sat}$: vapour pressure 
$\rho_{satL}$: saturated liquid density 
$\varepsilon,\;\sigma$: say, Lennard-Jones parameters

I know that the vapour pressure can be computed from the derivative w.r.t $V$, i.e. $P_{sat}=-(\partial A/\partial V)_T$ (although I have not tried to actually do it yet, by hand or code).

But I am struggling to understand how is the **saturated liquid** (or vapour) **density** computed from a Helmholtz free energy derivative (similar to that of vapour pressure). I read that *ancillary equations* have been used to compute saturated properties (https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=918040). However, SAFT EoS have been developed to predict properties below the critical temperature.

Can anyone please help me to understand how this works (theory, calculation, equation, code, etc.), or point me to any reference paper that explains about this (because I have not been able to find any...)?